# Tor unexpectedly exits

Tags: onion-services, mac

I tried to start a hidden service on mac with MAMP and tor browser. I added the line

```
HiddenServiceDir /Users/Gary/Desktop/tor_site
HiddenServicePort 4023 127.0.0.1:4023
```

into my `torrc` file in

```
Applications/TorBrowser.app/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/
```

and whenever it boots up it says

```
Tor unexpectedly exited. This might be due to a bug in Tor itself, another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you restart Tor, the Tor Browser will not able to reach any websites. If the problem persists, please send a copy of your Tor Log to the support team.
```

and when I click copy log to clipboard it says 0 lines copied. When I comment out the `HiddenService` lines it works but everything else, I get that message.

Comment: I've never done this before on mac but the Tor project docs on hidden service configuration https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en (step 2) suggests the 1st line should be something like `HiddenServiceDir /Library/Tor/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/` if you are using OS X Tor package.